# No se descarga archivo txt de ruta con c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net

Estoy haciendo una app web con c# que descarga un archivo txt de una ruta especifica, pero se ejecuta el codigo correctamente y no me descarga mi archivo

> ```
>     protected void btnDescargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         string ruta;
>         ruta = @"C:\Archivo\Reporte.txt";
>
>         Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
>         Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
>         Response.AppendHeader("NombreCabecera", "MensajeCabecera");
>         Response.TransmitFile(ruta);
>         Response.End();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba con el atriuto de htm5 ***download***

Puedes consultar mas sobre el aqui: [Atributo HTML5 Download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Te dejo un ejemplo.

Espero te sirva.

```js
document.getElementById('downloadBtn').setAttribute('href', `data:image/png;base64,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`);

document.getElementById('downloadBtn').click();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Atrubuto Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="downloadBtn" class="btn btn-primary" download style="display:none">Descargar</a>
</body>
</html>
```